# How to create a custom DSC resource with MOF

Tags: powershell, dsc

I'm trying to create a custom DSC resource using MOF, as per the instructions here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/authoringresourcemof. I've created the 3 files described and put them in `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\MyDscResources\DSCResources\MyCustomResource`

Import-DscResource appears to work ok, but when I try to use it in a node, it says it is undefined.

```
Configuration MyServerConfig
{
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName 'MyCustomResource' # this line succeeds

    Node MyServer
    {
        MyCustomResource MyCustomResource  # this line fails
        {
           Ensure = "Present"
           # ...
        }
    }
}
```

Results in:

```
Undefined DSC resource 'MyCustomResource'. Use Import-DSCResource to import the resource.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ResourceNotDefined
```

Is there any way I can get more useful error information to figure out what's wrong with my custom resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to create the resource by hand, the solution was to use xDSCResourceDesigner to generate all the files, as per this article http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2015/07/02/creating-a-simple-dsc-resource/

```
New-Item -Path "$env:ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules" -Name MyDSCResources -ItemType Directory
New-ModuleManifest -Path "$env:ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\MyDSCResources\MyDSCResources.psd1" -Guid (([guid]::NewGuid()).Guid) -Author 'Me' -ModuleVersion 1.0 -Description 'My DSC Resource Module' -PowerShellVersion 4.0 -FunctionsToExport '*.TargetResource'

$Name = New-xDscResourceProperty -Type String -Name Name -Attribute Key
$Ensure = New-xDscResourceProperty -Name Ensure -Type String -Attribute Write -ValidateSet "Present", "Absent"
#... more properties

New-xDscResource -Name MyCustomResource -Property $Name,$Ensure -Path "$env:ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\MyDSCResources" -ClassVersion 1.0 -FriendlyName MyCustomResource –Force
```

It seems there are a lot of fiddly settings to get right, and not enough error messages to guide you, so not worth doing by hand if you're new to DSC.

Thanks to @Nana for pushing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

MyCustomResource is the name of the resource. You need to specify the name of the module - in your case MyDscResources. So the Import-DscResource statement should look like this

Import-DscResource -ModuleName MyDscResources

Comment: Thanks, I did try that, but it failed at the import line:
`+     Import-DscResource -ModuleName 'MyDscResources'
Could not find the module 'MyDscResources'.`

Comment: Do you have a MyDscResources.psd1 available at c:\program files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\MyDscresources? If not can you make sure there is one. You can use the New-moduleManifest cmdlet to generate one

Comment: I've just tried that. `Import-DscResource -ModuleName 'MyDscResources'` now succeeds, but I'm back with the original problem `Undefined DSC resource 'MyCustomResource'. Use Import-DSCResource to import the resource.`

Answer (score 0):

You should have MyCustomResource.schema.mof and MyCustomResource.psm1 files under C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\MyDscResources\DSCResources\MyCustomResource folder. If 'Get-DscResource -module MyDscResources' is not displaying this resource than something is wrong with the resource. In that case can you share contents of MyCustomResource.schema.mof and signature of Get-TargetResource, Test-TargetResource and Set-TargetResource functions from MyCustomResource.psm1.

Comment: Thanks - i did have the schema.mof and psm1 files in the right place, but I expect there was something wrong with the manifest. Solved using xDSCResourceDesigner instead.